# Hide "Apps " link from left navigation of Mysite

Tags: mysite

How can I hide the "Apps" name from left navigation that appears on mysite of SharePoint. I know its a child site collection of mysite host, but is there any simple way to just hide it from there?

Answer (score 1):

you can choose css to hide the "Apps" element. Use :nth-child() Selector and then .hide()

:nth-child
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

.hide()
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Javascript to hide elements.

**EDIT:**  Whoops, I confused Javascript code with Jquery code.  Include JQuery into a javascript code.  The syntax of JQuery is

```
$(selector).hide(speed,callback);
```

Here's a link to read more: http://api.jquery.com/hide/